# Having java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory in JMeter 3 With Selenium JUnit tests

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

I'm writing some JUnit tests using the Selenium WebDriver APIs. The Selenium artifact is

```
groupId: org.seleniumhq.selenium
artifactId: selenium-java
version vers. 2.53.0 (the last at the moment)
```

I added my test's jar to the lib folder of JMeter 3 but I'm having this exception stack when I start JMeter

http://pastebin.com/nPG8k7yU

It seems it is a conflict in the jar dependencies, but the log doesn't tell where the conflict is.

What do you think the problem could be?

Thank you

Comment: I am not much aware about Selenium but this error arises when Jar or Class file is available at Compile Time but not available at Run Time. So,I think jar may not get loaded at run time.

Comment: Hi @Darshit. I'm not using the MenuFactory class in my jar. It's a JMeter's jar, so it is not required at compile time by my jar but only by JMEter to run the UI